# Is it possible to use the same intent with the same putextra value again?

Tags: android, android-intent

*New Edit* I updated the stack trace at the end of my question.

*Edit*

Below is the codes from another activity that is working. 
`bottom_nav_camera_yes_button` is an activity but I named as yes_button because the activity appears when I click `yes_button`.

```
yes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSave();
                pointCounter();
                //move to yes_button activity
                Intent int_yes = new Intent(bottom_nav_camera.this, bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.class);
                //passing the topLabels[0] to yes_button activity
                int_yes.putExtra("topLabels", topLabels[0]);
                startActivity(int_yes);
            }
        });
```

I am reusing the same `putExtra("topLabels", label)` for two different activities, but whenever I include this line, the app completely closes. Is there any way to reuse the same `putExtra` variable?

```
yes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //move to yes_button activity
                Intent int_yes = new Intent(bottom_nav_camera_no_button_details.this, bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.class);
                //passing the topLabels[0] to yes_button activity
                int_yes.putExtra("topLabels", label);
                startActivity(int_yes);
            }
        });
```

stack trace

```
2020-04-04 17:58:33.838 15812-15812/com.codepath.wmgf8 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codepath.wmgf8, PID: 15812
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codepath.wmgf8/com.codepath.wmgf8.bottom_nav_camera_yes_button}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.codepath.wmgf8.bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.displayPhoto(bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.java:103)
        at com.codepath.wmgf8.bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.onCreate(bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.java:87)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem may not be here your exception may be in `bottom_nav_camera_yes_button` when you get the extra and try to get its length but the extra is null

as stack trace says:

> Unable to start activity
>   `ComponentInfo{com.codepath.wmgf8/com.codepath.wmgf8.bottom_nav_camera_yes_button}`:
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to get length of null array

look for line 103 in `bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.java` (the `displayPhoto()` method)

> at
>   `com.codepath.wmgf8.bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.displayPhoto`(`bottom_nav_camera_yes_button.java`:103)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe `bottom_nav_camera_yes_button` is an activity becaue it was working for another activity.

Comment: @lim I do not think so because the name of `bottom_nav_camera_yes_button` ends with button not activity it may be a button

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just named the activity as button because the activity appears when I click yes_button (detailed explanation shown on my edited question).

Comment: @lim if your app is crashing please add stack trace to your question

Comment: I just added my stack trace. Please let me know if there is anything I need to add.

Comment: @lim there is no crash report in your stack trace it is not reporting that your activity closed with exception. send stack trace when your app crashes (it should be in red color in android studio)

Comment: @lim your problem may not be here your exception may be in `bottom_nav_camera_yes_button` when you get the extra and try to get its length but the extra is null

Comment: All thanks to your help, I found the problem--it was because I did not create the folder when I initiate with the new activity, so it has a null string because it could not read the folder's name.